# New Item not opening in side pane after adding Task Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

I was messing around with Content Types and now when people click on "New" or "Edit", SharePoint takes them to a full page instead of a form that slides open from the side.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

[image: Sharepoint List]
[image: After Clicking New]

Comment: You might accidentally have turned classic mode on? If so you should have a link under the left hand navigation that says "Exit classic experience"

Comment: Hello Rune, I dont see that option anywhere. I can confirm that this happens after i add new content type, i removed the content type and its columns since, but clicking new page still takes me to the the full page form unfortunately.

Comment: What kind of list or library is this?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question. It's just a normal sharepoint list. Sorry.

Comment: No worries! When you click the new button, is that on the top of the page in a ribbon, or right above the list? You can edit your question and include screenshots.

Comment: Ruse, I've uploaded screenshots, hope this helps. The new button is right above the list

Comment: Check list settings, advanced. At the bottom it says something about list experience? There is another setting also for opening as a dialog.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106306/discussion-between-aaron-and-rune-sperre).

Comment: I checked that setting and it is set to yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated answer after more information and testing.

When you added the **Task** Content Type to the list, the field **Related Items** was added to the list.

This field cannot be deleted from the list once added it seems:

```
❯ (Get-PnPField -List tasktest -Identity "Related Items").CanBeDeleted
False
```

Additionally, this field type (also called Related Items) is not listed in
 [Supported columns in modern view](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/modern-view-compatibility-checklist#the-form-page-contains-columns-that-are-incompatible-with-modern). Unfortuenately, setting the field to hidden as suggested there has no impact.

There does not seem to be any way to update the field so that it can be deleted, If you open a service request with Microsoft they might be able to help you further.

Recreating the list and migrating existing items seems to be the most feasible solution here. You can preserve modified/author information if you do this using a script or a migration tool like ShareGate.

Comment: Rune, can you try this to see if you can reproduce the problem. Im sorry to keep commenting. List settings > Add content type > choose task and submit. Then delete the content type and add new item again. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, i managed to reproduce the error by setting the mentioned setting to 'Classic'. Don't worry about commenting - it is your question :-)

Comment: My settings was on default, i switch to classic, save then switch to new experience and back. Seem like adding new content type somehow broke the form?

Comment: Sorry, I did not catch the detail about that this was the Task content type. I indeed have the same problem now. I will get back to you.

Comment: No solution yet, but I have located the problem. It is most likely the "Related Items" column that was added - that cannot be deleted. Is recreating the list an option?

Comment: Thanks Rune! Unfortunately recreating the list is not an option at the moment. Unless there are absolutely no way to resolve.

Comment: I've tried every trick I can think of now, and it doesn't look good. I updated my answer with these findings and recommendation.